# Is there a way to keep screen awake in a progressive-web-app?

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I plan to make a progressive web app to display the time remaining in a meeting. I need this to keep the display always on. Is there any way for a progressive web app to avoid screen to go to sleep and blank ?

Comment: You may refer with this [chrome.power](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/power) API to override the system's power management features. By default, operating systems dim the screen when users are inactive and eventually suspend the system. With the power API, an app or extension can keep the system awake. Here's an example for [chrome.power Plugin](https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/cordova-plugin-chrome-apps-power).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Update July 2020**:
Chrome 84 now ships with the Wake Lock API https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/4636879949398016 which can be used to prevent the screen from turning off.

---

You could use the [Standby API](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5768542523752448) however support is still limited.

Then there are hacks such as playing a video infinitely or the [nosleep](https://github.com/richtr/NoSleep.js) script, however from my experience they don't work consistently either.

Comment: Nowadays, NoSleep.js preferably uses the Wake Lock API if available. Also, it seems the Standby API got superseded by this new API.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the documentation for the **Wake Lock** option in Chrome:
https://developer.chrome.com/articles/wake-lock/

Note that it's only available on HTTPS. (Normally not an issue, although some non-public internal applications can be standard HTTP.)